# Babel doesn't seem to change anything

Tags: javascript, babeljs

When I try to convert my js file using Babel it doesn't work properly.

**index.js**

```
const sum = (a,b) => 
{
  return a+b;
};

console.log(suma(1,3))
```

And the result using yarn babel src/index.js --out-file public/bundle.js

**bundle.js**

```
const soma = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};

console.log(soma(1, 3));
```

Isn't the bundle supposed to be different? Converting the arrow function?

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ],
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.35.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```

There is no error messages in the process, it simply doesn't change anything from the index to the bundle.js.

Comment: The index.js and bundle.js you posted don't match

Comment: sorry, i made some changes in the index at the time that I posted the code